# Linux Mint & Dell Inspiron 17 7000 Series: Wifi Turned OFF

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I can not turn on wifi in my dell laptop. The software wireless switch is off and I can not turn it on. As soon as you try to flick it to ON it moves back to OFF.

I have just installed Linux Mint from scratch in it. The wifi used to work originally weeks weeks ago but I borrowed the laptop to other person and it does not work now. the laptop used to have windows system installed. So, when I opened windows it had the same problem: wifi turned off and airplane mode on.

So, i decided to wipe all of and install linux in it to see if the problem is caused by windows and it is not ...

i tried:

```
rfkill unblock wifi
rfkill list all
```

`rkill list all` returns:

```
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
              Soft blocked: yes
              Hard blockeD: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
         Soft blocked: no
         Hard blocked: no
```

I have tried rfkill unblock all It does not help ..

I have tried as well Fn + Antenna button next to PrtScr and it does not work. I have tried antenna button on its own and it does not help...

there is no hardware wifi switch ...

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless card might be disabled in your BIOS.

To enter your BIOS, when the Dell logo appears tap F2 key until the message Entering Setup appears.

Look for : Power Management-> Wireless Radio control-> Control WLAN Radio or something along those lines, and make sure it is always on.

Comment: i had a look into bios before i asked questio. no such option in my bios, no info about network at all...

Comment: Well, Dell has been known for providing bad network cards, even on their high end models. Update your BIOS, make sure you're using the latest drivers, chances are you might need to replace the network controller in the end (like most people did when you search for this issue online)